# Typeorm creates migration file at the root

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typeorm, nest

I'm generating migrations using TypeOrm in NestJS but I don't know why it creates the migration file at the root every time and I want it to automatically create the migration file into `/src/server/migration/` folder.

`ormconfig.ts`

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

dotenv.config();

const connection = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres' as const,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'database',
  entities: ['src/server/entity/*.{ts,js}'],
  migrations: ['src/server/migration/*.{ts,js}'],
  extra: {
    ssl: false,
  },
});

export default connection;
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm --dataSource ./ormconfig.ts",
    "migration:gen": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -n",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typeorm": "^0.3.6",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`typeorm@0.2.x` → `typeorm@0.3.x` is a breaking change. Since `0.3.x`, [you have to specify full path<sup>1</sup> to the migration file](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8814#issuecomment-1080945772):

```bash
typeorm migration:generate ./path/to/migration
```

<sup>1</sup> – *Kinda, because the last piece of the path will be prefixed with the timestamp and suffixed with `.ts`.*

---

FWIW, most of the comments in the linked GitHub issue are either confused or negative, – a lot of developers didn't appreciate this change. One of the core maintainers of the repo has [drawn conclusion](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3267) that the community "negatively accepts big changes".